# "Contact us to request deletion" link does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, help-center

On the page [Deleting account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) the bottom link "Contact us to request deletion" points to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion` which only redirects back to the same page. Tested (in Chrome) on meta.SO and also on Math.SE.

(To be clear, I'm *not* asking my account to be deleted, only reporting a bug.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link has been corrected to point to the contact us page.

Answer (score 7):

I think it *should* link to [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and cause the proper item to be auto selected:

> [image]